# Converting military time to standard time using Moment.js

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, datetime-conversion

I'm getting an error when I try to use Moment.js to convert military time to standard 12 hour time. In my template I pass `moment()` an object that contains the time from a UI time picker, then I provide the desired format.

The terminal error says:

> Parser Error: Unexpected token (, expected identifier or keyword at column 8 in [ 
>   [15:17:43] {{moment.(event.eventTime, hh:mm A)}}

```html
<ion-col>
    <ion-icon name="clock"></ion-icon>
    <BR>
    {{ moment.(event.eventTime, hh:mm A) }}
</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment). You can use:

- *(if `event.eventTime` is a string)* [`amParse`](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment#amparse-pipe) pipe to parse your `event.eventTime` into a moment object (the pipe uses [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) parsing function). I'm supposing *military time* is in `HH:mm` format (e.g. `00:00`, `15:30`, etc)
- [`amDateFormat`](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment#amdateformat-pipe) pipe to display moment object in the desired format (`hh:mm A`)

Your code could be like the following:

```
{{ event.eventTime | amParse:'HH:mm' | amDateFormat:'hh:mm A' }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the format you want is:

```
{{moment(event.eventTime).format("hh:mm A")}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's built-in [date format pipes](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

```
{{ dateObj | date:'shortTime' }}
```